# Python Request Aborted - ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

Tags: python, exception, connection, telegram

i am running into the following error with the code provided here...
i have tried changing timeout, delay, headers, etc. - nothing has solved it.

code below - please help with a fix if you know of anything i might be able to try...

also to note - the script should check t.me as well as fragment - not either or... not sure if i've structured it correctly here

---

```
   for word in words:
        if progress_bar == True:
            bar.next() # next % in progress bar

        if isinstance(words_array, str):
            word = word.replace("\n", "")  # remove line breaks
        elif isinstance(words_array, list):
            word = word.replace(" ", "")  # remove spaces

        # Checking symbols in word
        symbols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l','m', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '_']
        word_symbols = list(word)
        valid_symbols = 0

        for symbol in word_symbols:
            if symbol in symbols:
                valid_symbols += 1
        # /. # Checking symbols in word
        if len(word_symbols) == valid_symbols:
            # Set a retry limit and delay
            retry_limit = 25  # increased from 5
            delay = 5.0  # increased from 0.5

            # Create a for loop that will run until the retry limit is reached
            try:
                # Make the request
                time.sleep(0.01)
                telegram_web = requests.get(
                    f'https://t.me/{word.lower()}', headers=headers, timeout=60)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(telegram_web.text, 'html.parser')
                elements_list = soup.find_all(
                    "div", {"class": "tgme_page_extra"})

            except ConnectionResetError:
                # Delay for a certain amount of time before making the request again
                # so that the server isn't overloaded
                time.sleep(delay)
                delay *= 2

            else:
                # Execute code if there is no error
                if len(elements_list) == 0:
                    # Check word for sale/sold in Fragment.com
                    time.sleep(0.01)
                    fragment = requests.get(
                        f'https://fragment.com/username/{word.lower()}', headers=headers, timeout=30)
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(fragment.text, 'html.parser')
                    avail_status = soup.find_all(
                        "tr", {"class": "tm-section-header-status tm-status-avail"})
                    sold_status = soup.find_all(
                        "tr", {"class": "tm-section-header-status tm-status-unavail"})
                    # /. Check word for sale/sold in Fragment.com
                    if len(avail_status) == 0 and len(sold_status) == 0:
                        checked_words.append(word)
            continue

    if progress_bar == True:
        bar.finish() # remove progress bar
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem when connect python with firebase, using spyder IDE, I was stuck in 4 hours =)))
Solution is.....I create new python file, copy old code paste in this new file and run again then it will work for me,
Hope it will help you too (I saw your topic while I was struggling with my problem (same error sentence))
Predict problem: I think maybe it because the library set oauth connection error for this python file